# JavaScript setInterval scope issue: an alternative to bind

Tags: javascript, class, scope, setinterval

I just correct a scope problem in my JavaScript Class with bind method that put the function called by setInterval in the right scope. But it seams bind has come early (1.8.4 I think) and I'm worry with browser compatibility.

Is there another older alternative? Should I forget about old browsers?

Example:

```
function MyClass(SomeText){
  this.text = SomeText;
}

MyClass.prototype.test = function(){
  console.log("The text: "+this.text);
}

MyClass.prototype.initialize = function(){
  setInterval(this.test.bind(this), 1000);
}

var Test = new MyClass("my thoughts");
Test.initialize();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The alternative is a good ol' closure:

```
MyClass.prototype.initialize = function(){
    var myClassInstance = this;
    setInterval(function() {
        myClassInstance.test()
    }, 1000);
}
```

Isn't exactly pretty, but does work cross-browser.

If you want something similar to bind, you can create your own function to do that, or use [the polyfill found at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). If you're using jQuery, you can use [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), that does the same thing.

Comment: +1 Beat me by 15sec. If you use jQuery, there's `$.proxy`. There's also a `bind` polyfill at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Thanks, added the info from your comment to the answer, for completeness.

Comment: So it's a prototype usage limitation, if we want to keep it working in old browsers. Thanks.

Comment: @GustavoPinent It's a limitation with Function.prototype.bind, which is not available on older browsers. It has nothing to do with using prototype methods on your classes or not. In fact, the same problem happens with instance own methods.

Comment: I don't get your point, if bind is not available, you can't use prototype in this case, right?

Comment: @Gustavo I don't get what you don't get! ;-) Doesn't my answer show a way to use the prototype method without bind? My point is, this has nothing to do with the method belonging to the prototype; if it were defined inside the constructor (`this.someMethod = function(){...}`), you'd have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I just understood when modifying my code a moment ago! Forgive-me!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm glad you got it! @GustavoPinent